# How to view Linux email folder (something@email.com) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, linux

When I backup email folders from my webhost (on Linux) to my Windows 7, inside the folder, there is a list of files or folders named, for example, `john@email.com` or  `mary@email.com`. These directories are accessible on Linux OS, but on Windows, it appears as an MS-DOS file.

Is there any way I can view it under Windows?

Comment: What do you use to read your email messages on Linux? Can you describe your set up?

Comment: on linux shell, i can access directly to this folder usr/home/mail/*  i backed up these file into win7, i am trying to find out how to view it

Comment: @rick99 Please follow up on the question, it would be interesting and useful to know if any of the suggestions helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This `usr/home/mail/*` looks like a Mutt path, probably try using

- http://unixmail-w32.sourceforge.net/ (easy to install) or
- http://www.mutt.org/download.html with cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use IMAP to download the mail into an email program on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If the mailboxes are *files*, you can open them with any text editor, or with such mail programs as Mutt or re-Alpine. They're likely to be in `mbox` format, with all messages as plain text in a single file. You're seeing the MS-DOS executable icon simply because the file names end with `.com`, which is treated by Windows as an executable extension.

*<sub>Inb4 "extensions are fail" comments: MS-DOS COM executables did not have any magic number, so any attempt to differentiate between them and `mbox` archives would be pure guessing.</sub>*